# Google Sheets import range returning incorrect data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

The full google spread sheet system is used for score keeping and is prone to delays when updating, however I have never run into an issue like this were the same basic function is returning two separate results. The problem is repeatable and occurs on more than one spreadsheet.

I have created a test sheet-
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1arh0D9ch5MpQjRh_bHjLfLx5S7TAW8R_pgGLf5tovig/
with the code in question; Can anyone help please?

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("***","***"),"select Col1 where Col1 <>5 order by Col9 desc")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `QUERY` formula you are selecting cells that are numeric and comparing it to `<>5` but take a notice that A2 is not numeric:

[image: 0]

that is the reason why `2 2` is not included in your **C** column

also it looks like that your `QUERY` formula smashed first cells into one because you did not specify the 3td query parameter. try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1pnowvo6YVj-DZAPCaKE2x9vSIbpAAmlwhRMO2OZNlrE","color!A84:M115"),
 "select Col1 where Col1 <>5 order by Col9 desc", 0)
```

Comment: The code on the left is showing both 2's, just as the one on the right is. Just in one cell which is not what it's supposed to be doing. I'm stumped.

Comment: Your updated answer that included the ,0 fixed it perfectly, now I just need to figure out how to upvote you. Do you also have a solution for all the grey hair this has caused me?

Comment: @FootballGuy your reputation points are low now so you are not able to upvote stuff. but you can accept the answer as solved if it helped you.